# ASP.NET MVC após atualizar os pacotes o template padrão se perde?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, mvc

Sou novo nesta área, estou "caminhando descalço nas pedras" para aprender ASP.NET, uso o VISUAL STUDIO 2017 Community 2017 Versão 15.8.4.

Ao criar um novo projeto ASP.NET MVC o visual studio gera uma aplicação vazia com um menu.

Ao atualizar os pacotes via Console do Gerenciador de Pacotes essa aplicação perde o menu e suas funcionalidades.

Acredito que seja por conta da atualização do Bootstrap e demais scripts.

Confesso que estou no escuro sem o modelo que o ASP.NET MVC cria para me orientar, já vi no site do Bootstrap que a versão atual é 4.1. Já no modelo criado com o ASP.NET MVC a versão é 3.3.7. 
Ou seja, não pode atualizar os pacotes do modelo criado?

Alguém já passou por essa situação, perder a formatação da página por conta disso ?

Já pesquisei vários modelos e exemplos, mas todos que encontrei se baseiam em versões mais antigas, os modelos no site do Bootstrap estão bem diferentes.

A minha falta de experiência me diz que já devo ter a resposta mas não estou sabendo interpretá-la.

Desde já, agradeço aos amigos que puderem me dar uma direção a seguir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A versão nova do bootstrap tem algumas break changes.

Uma alternativa é você fixar no packages.config a versão do pacote.

```
<package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.7" targetFramework="net472" allowedVersions="[3.3.7]" />
```

Ou atualizar o seu template conforme as novas especificações do [boostrap 4.1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Pablo!

Comment: Feito!
Adicionando essa restrição a versão do Bootstrap se mantem e o modelo criado com o ASP.NET MVC não perde a sua formatação nem seu funcionamento.
Grato pela atenção Pablo!